# Undefined symbols for arcitecture x86_64 when I try to use GRANSAC code from github

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, ransac

I'm trying to use GRANSAC(Generic RANSAC) from this github repository. https://github.com/drsrinathsridhar/GRANSAC
When I build with cmake, this error happens and I don't know how to solve it.

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_omp_get_max_threads",
>   referenced from:
>         GRANSAC::RANSAC::Estimate(std::__1::vector,
>   std::__1::allocator >
>
> > const&) in LineFittingSample.cpp.o
> >           GRANSAC::RANSAC::RANSAC() in LineFittingSample.cpp.o   "_omp_get_thread_num", referenced from:
> >           GRANSAC::RANSAC::Estimate(std::__1::vector,
> >     std::__1::allocator >
> >     const&) in LineFittingSample.cpp.o   "_omp_set_dynamic", referenced from:
> >           GRANSAC::RANSAC::Estimate(std::__1::vector,
> >     std::__1::allocator >
> >     const&) in LineFittingSample.cpp.o   "_omp_set_num_threads", referenced from:
> >           GRANSAC::RANSAC::Estimate(std::__1::vector,
> >     std::__1::allocator >
> >     const&) in LineFittingSample.cpp.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
> >     1 (use -v to see invocation) make[2]: *** [LineFittingSample] Error 1
> >     make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/LineFittingSample.dir/all] Error 2 make: ***
> >     [all]
>
> Error 2

Environment: MacOS Mojave ver 10.14.16

Comment: You probably need the OpenMP stuff as shown here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/58276476/2836621

Comment: This link may be better if you are using `cmake` https://stackoverflow.com/a/49739810/2836621

Comment: I checked both of links but I still cannot solve the problem. Could you explain how to do it a bit more detail?

Comment: The first line of your error message is from the linker. It means your code compiled correctly but the linker couldn't find the library that contains the code for `_omp_get_max_threads` which is part of **OpenMP**. So the problem is that you are not correctly finding and linking the **OpenMP** libraries. So, you either need to install **OpenMP** if you have not already, or upgrade your `cmake` version so it can find them, or you need to improve your `CMakeLists.txt` to help it find **OpenMP** better - maybe by giving it hints.